# Get 12 hour time from Time Helper in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, time

I'm using the `niceShort` function in the Time Helper in Cake to display some times from my database. It works wonderfully, but it would be great to be able to have `niceShort` use 12 hour time instead of 24. Is there a way to do this without modifying the helper?

Answer (score 1):

To make a 12-hour time, simply do this in your view:

```
<?php echo $time->format('g:la', $string); ?>
```

For a list of all of the different formatting options, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

In other words, my above example `(g:la)` would output `4:45pm`

Answer (score 1):

I still wanted to be able to use the `nice` and `niceShort` functions, so I modified the Time helper and moved it into app/views/helpers.

.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`format`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1471/Formatting) function and provide the date/time format you want. It is the same format string as the [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function in PHP.

Comment: Its not the same. We can use H for 24 hrs and h for 12 hrs in date() but format() of cakephp does not support h for 12 hrs format.

Answer (score 0):

As cakephp's format() uses PHP's strftime() formatting options. You can use

```
%I:%M %p or %r 
echo $this->Time->format($news['News']['modified'],'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p');
```

it will format for example: 21:34:17 to 09:34:17 PM. You can read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).